# Why is my Java LocalDate being saved as the Previous Day inside Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, micronaut, micronaut-data

## Summary

**If I create a Java `LocalDate` object (ex: "*2023-09-28*") and save it to my Postgres db the previous day gets stored (ex: "*2023-09-27*").**

- The stored database value is *always* 1 day behind

## Code

Here is my code (micronaut):

```
@MappedEntity("event")
data class Event(

    @field:Id val id: UUID,

    val date: LocalDate // <===
)

@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
interface EventRepository: CrudRepository<Event, UUID> {}
```

Here is how I save it:

```
    val date = LocalDate.parse("2023-09-28", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)

    val newEvent = Event(id, date)
    repo.save(newEvent)
```

The logs show the right values being sent:

```
DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing SQL query: INSERT INTO "event" ("date","id") VALUES (?,?)
TRACE io.micronaut.data.query - Binding parameter at position 1 to value 2023-09-28 with data type: DATE
```

## Database

I'm using this driver: `"org.postgresql:postgresql"`

- https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc

My postges table is using column type `date`:

```sql
create table event
(
    id   uuid not null,
    date date not null
);
```

- Postgres: date (no time of day)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.htm

## Runnable Example

I have a minimal reproducible example here:

- https://github.com/jxc876/localdate-bug

## Research

Could possibly be related to this?

"LocalDate conversion should ignore timezones"

- https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/2221

Comment: Your DB is in differerent timezone than your app.

Comment: @Antoniossss I thought about that as well, but this field type doesn't store TimeZone information, wondering why timezone would matter.

Comment: its a DATE, therefore it is affected by the timezone. If you want it to be store "as is" make it a string

Comment: My advice is to always use UTC timezone across the system if it is viable (aside of beeing timezone aware as it would work as well). In such case, results are indeed "human readable".